# Integrating Multi-Channel External Payment Gateway with CiviCRM/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, payment-processor

I've been working with a client in Indonesia to get up and running on CiviCRM to help raise money online, and better keep track of those donations.

We are working with an external payment gateway that offers a variety of payment channels, ie. credit card, bank transfers, direct debit, mobile-phone credit transfers and payment at convenience store kiosks. This broad range of channels is a real blessing for us, but I just realized that when I added the payment processor to our install of CiviCRM, the "payment_type" was set to a static choice (credit card, or direct debit). As a result, transactions will always be listed in available report templates as a payment_type representing that static choice, rather than the wealth of options that are available via the external payment gateway.

Is there a way to allow for the payment gateway to pass back the information on the payment_type and for to store that info in the database somewhere? And if so, where would that info be stored?

We are running CiviCRM 4.7.16 on Wordpress 4.7. The custom payment processor extension the folks at the payment gateway built for us is available at: https://github.com/rizdaprasetya/vtweb-civicrm

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.